# Fast cryptographic hash function for short inputs

Tags: hash, implementation, pseudo-random-generator

I am looking for a cryptographic hash function optimized for speed on short inputs, in order to implement a pseudorandom generator with expansion factor 2 (e.g. takes 16 bytes of input and outputs 32 pseudorandom bytes).

Here are some natural candidates I tried:

- SHA256: good baseline
- Blake2: designed for speed on large inputs, does not perform as well on short inputs
- AES-CTR: faster than SHA256 when the hardware supports [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set). The input is used as a key for AES to encrypt a predefined byte array of the desired output length. However, re-initializing the cipher for each call to the hash function is costly.

I also found this interesting construction: [STHash](https://github.com/jedisct1/rust-sthash). It is a keyed cryptographic hash function optimized for speed on *large* inputs. I don't mind having a keyed hash function instead of a general-purpose one.

Is there any analogous construction for *short* inputs, or a more efficient way to leverage AES-NI than AES-CTR?

### Some informal benchmarks

For each hash function, I hash an array of 16 bytes into a 32 bytes array, and I repeat 10 million times. For stream ciphers like AES and ChaCha, I create a new cipher at each iteration with the input as key on a public fixed plaintext and nonce. If the cipher needs a 32-bit key, I just pad the input with 0. If the hash function does not produce enough bits (e.g. SipHash outputs only 128 bits), I run it several times.

I am running Rust Nightly on an Intel® Core™ i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz × 8, the experiments run on a single thread.

- SipHash 1-3: 476.9ms
- Chacha8: 590.4ms
- SipHash: 670.3ms
- AES-128: 665.3ms
- SHA256: 780.4ms
- Blake2s: 1413.9ms

For information, some results about Haraka (using a not well-known optimized implementation):

- Haraka-v2 256-5: 55.2ms
- Haraka-v2 256-6: 69.9ms

Comment: Could you try Chacha or  HChacha and then post your answer with good charts?

Comment: Another thing to think about, other than @kelalaka's suggestion of (H)ChaCha, would be Haraka v2 (https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/098), which is specifically designed as a short-input hash for post-quantum hash-based schemes. SipHash is short-input, but entirely unusable as a general-purpose hash.

Comment: And, actually, you can post your current results, and add new ones over time. During this, you will get more comments and points :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I didn't know Haraka, and I'm astonished by its performances. I used this (not well-known) implementation: https://github.com/gendx/haraka-rs. Is it expected that Haraka is more than 2 orders of magnitude faster than SHA256 or ChaCha?

Comment: Haraka uses the AES instruction set to accelerate its performance, and is designed from the start for short inputs. Try running 1MB through that vs SHA256 on a system without AESNI, and you will see a very different result

Comment: **Caution**: AES (esp. AES-256) is not designed to be used with adversaries in control of "input used as a key", that is for resistance to related-key attacks. Things are not as bad as with TEA being used that way in the hash for the code authentication of the Xbox (1) but that's still a dangerous line. Post Scriptum: Details on that hash-second-preimage attack of the Xbox become hard to find, there's not much in [this](https://cs.oberlin.edu/~ctaylor/classes/341F2012/xbox.pdf).

Comment: This is a good point, thank you @fgrieu. I edited the (informal) benchmarks for clarity and restated that I am unsure about the Haraka implementation. The paper claims around 0.6 cycles per byte, and the implementation linked above seems optimized and might leverage more than one thread. I am happy if someone wants to reproduce the results!

Comment: @d1v: better. Again [these numbers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/84450/5) for [Haraka v2](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/098.pdf) are physically impossible. One possibility is that the number of loops is off by a factor like 100. Another is that some optimizer notices that the result of the multiple loops is demonstrably identical, or demonstrably unused, and optimizes almost everything out. Benchmarking is hard.

Comment: @fgrieu Indeed, it turned out that the compiler was optimizing away the result because it was unused - sorry. The [Haraka-v2 Rust crate](https://github.com/gendx/haraka-rs/blob/master/src/haraka256.rs#L153) also provides benchmarks that confirm 5ns per iteration. It remains my fastest candidate so far.

Comment: Can you clarify your "cryptographic" requirements? There are a lot of distinct aspects which depend on your use case. For some uses, SipHash or perhaps HighwayHash seems fine, for others, ChaCha8 might be good, for others you really want SHA-2 or SHA-3.

Comment: @fgrieu If you ever want to know more about how the original Xbox was hacked, let me know.  I came up with the A20 attack from that document =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[For devices with the AES-NI instruction set]

I highly recommend looking at the Davies-Meyer construction based on fixed-key AES. By now, it has been used in dozens of different works, and though it is of course not a perfectly standard assumption on AES, it is quite widely accepted as a plausible one. In particular, it provably yields a PRG when modeling AES as a random permutation.

The construction is as follows:

- Fix two keys $(K_0, K_1)$ once for all. They are public and will never change, hence you will only have to do the key schedule twice.
- On input $x$ of size 16 Bytes, output $(\mathsf{AES}_{K_0}(x) \oplus x,\mathsf{AES}_{K_1}(x) \oplus x)$.

Note the crucial XOR with $x$ (the construction would of course be insecure without it, as AES is invertible given the keys). A similar variant of the above, which requires a single key schedule and provides the same security (when modeling AES as a permutation) is:

- Fix one key $K$ once for all.
- On input $x$ of size 16 Bytes, output $(\mathsf{AES}_{K}(x) \oplus x,\mathsf{AES}_{K}(x\oplus 1) \oplus (x\oplus 1))$.

To read more about this approach, [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/074) is the proper starting point. In particular, you will see discussions on related constructions achieving different security properties. I don't think the paper directly proves that the exact constructions I sketched above are PRGs (when modeling AES as a random permutation), but the proof techniques that they use (using Patarin's H-coefficient technique) can be easily adapted to prove it (I worked out this exact analysis over the summer).

There are dozens of papers using this construction to implement the PRG required for the GGM pseudorandom function. This is especially common for implementing function secret sharing, or for building MPC-in-the-head post-quantum signatures (I can provide a sample of pointers upon request).

As for speed, fixed-key AES with the AES-NI assumption can be as fast as 1.3 cycles per Byte, which seems *very* hard to beat (XORs are of course super fast as well, especially using vector instructions). See e.g. [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1493) for a reference that indicates this number.

**=== EDIT (answering OP's comment below) ===**

As far as I know, Davies-Meyer and Matyas-Meyer-Oseas are two slightly incorrect ways of referring to the same construction (the one I described above). Originally, both Davies-Meyer and Matyas-Meyer-Oseas are compression functions to be used in hash function constructions from block ciphers:

- Davies-Meyer: $H_i = E_{m_i}(H_{i-1}) \oplus H_{i-1}$ (*i.e.* the next block is computed from the previous block using the current message block $m_i$ as the key)
- Matyas-Meyer-Oseas: $H_i = E_{g(H_{i-1})}(m_i) \oplus m_i$ (*i.e.* the next block is computed from the message block using the some function of the previous block as the key)

In our context, the key is always fixed anyway and there is no compression function - we're building a PRG. But the design is somewhat analogeous to either of the above and can be seen as either with a slight abuse of definitions of what counts as the previous block and what counts as a message block.

I think the terminology Matyas-Meyer-Oseas was the one originally used [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/074), but later works (e.g. [this one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1014.pdf)) switched to Davies-Meyer, probably because it felt a slightly more accurate naming (but both are debatable).

Comment: Notable fact: the single-key variant is distinguishable from a random function even without knowledge of $K$, because complementing the low-order bit of input $x$ exchanges the halves of the output. However, when the goal is collision-resistance or preimage resistance, that's a non-issue (at worse the cost of brute force w.r.t. cost of an evaluation would be halved). This property can even be a feature when we have to compute or/and store the hashes of consecutive values. And if undesirable, this property can be removed if we restrict input to 127 bits.

Comment: Indeed! But here my claim is precisely about *pseudorandomness* where the game is the following: $x$ is sampled uniformly at random, and a coin is tossed. If the coin returns 0, I send you the output $\mathsf{PRG}(x)$, which has length $2|x|$. If the coin returns 1, I send you a random bitstring of length $2|x|$. The PRG is secure if your advantage over the random guess in guessing what the coin toss was is negligible.

Comment: Thank you! It's been a while since my original post, but at the time I ended up using the Matyas-Meyer-Oseas construction, which looks similar to what you suggest. My use case was indeed function secret sharing, so I followed existing FSS work such as [Splinter](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/nsdi17/nsdi17-wang-frank.pdf). Could you elaborate on the difference between Davies-Meyer and Matyas-Meyer-Oseas?

Comment: I answered in the post directly, since it does not fit in a short comment :)

Answer (score 2):

These days, on CPUs with AES hardware acceleration, [Areion512](https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/article/view/10279) looks like a perfect fit and is likely to beat other options from a performance perspective.

Areion512 is a very efficient 512-bit permutation based on the AES round function.

Since introducing a key is an option, you can use $P(m \oplus k) \oplus k$ to efficiently expand 16 bytes into 32 bytes ($P$ being the Areion512 permutation and $m$ padded to 32 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try SipHash, especially the reduced-round version SipHash-1-3?

It was explicitly designed for short input, doesn’t require key expansion, is fast on pretty much all kind of architectures, and can output 64 or 128 bit.

The name might be confusing, though: a key is required, but since you mentioned that it wasn’t an issue for your use case, give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, SipHash 1-3 performs quite well (I edited the benchmarks). However I am unsure of the cryptographic strength of SipHash: the documentation mentions "Although the SipHash algorithm is considered to be generally strong, it is not intended for cryptographic purposes. As such, all cryptographic uses of this implementation are strongly discouraged." Also, since the output is just 128 bits, I have to run it several times to produce 32 bytes). Is SipHash suitable for a cryptographic PRG?

Comment: @d1v: SipHash positively requires a (128-bit) **secret** key to be secure against collision. SipHash-2-4 (with secret key) is the minimum parametrization that I see supported as safe in the [defining paper](https://cr.yp.to/siphash/siphash-20120620.pdf). But if SipHash-1-3 is broken, I missed it. The best attack I found is in [_Differential Cryptanalysis of SipHash_](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/865.pdf). Also see Christoph Dobraunig's [master thesis](https://diglib.tugraz.at/download.php?id=576a776e63870&location=browse).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HighwayHash](https://github.com/google/highwayhash). It is a fast SIMD-based keyed hash function (5x faster than [SipHash](https://www.131002.net/siphash/)) with [security claims](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06257) and suitable for hashing short inputs.

[image]

Comment: As for their security claim, to quote the paper: "We are not experienced cryptographers", "we rely on statistical testing to validate our main claim" - I wouldn't rely on that very heavily at all...